# "iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?

Tags: itunes, osx-mavericks

How can I get rid of this message OSX 10.9.4.  I have firewall set to accept incoming network connections for iTunes. "Do you want the application "iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?"

I have reinstalled the iTunes app and nothing changed.  I have rebooted after reinstall and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced older hard drive with a new SSD. First fresh reinstall of everything in years, but copied over my user profile to keep settings; thought this was the cause.

Fought with it for several days until I found this terminal command: `codesign -v --verbose /Applications/iTunes.app`.

It kept telling me my iTunes install had been altered and had extra font files.

I opened the package contents, deleted the listed font files and started iTunes. For the first time in weeks, it did not ask for network access.

I plan on running this for a while, and will update later if it changes.